# SQL Select most popular items in each store

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

## Update 3

Spent some hours reading on SQL and got this:

```
SELECT 
  StoreID, 
  Products
FROM (
  SELECT
    StoreID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StoreID ORDER BY Frequency DESC) AS Ordering,
    Products,
    Frequency
    FROM (
      SELECT
        StoreID,
        Products,
        COUNT(Products) AS Frequency
      FROM 
        StoreRecords
      WHERE 
        StoreGroupID =  1122
      GROUP BY 1,2
      ORDER BY StoreID, Frequency
    ) AS Output
)
WHERE 
  Ordering = 1
```

## Update 2

Apologies for the poor context. Further clarification:

- I have a table that tracks the products sold at each of my stores, for a given day
- It has 2 columns: Store ID and Product name
- I would like to write a query that returns each of the store ID, along with the products with the highest sale volume
- This means when iPhone has the highest sales volume at Store A, the row will return Store A, iPhone

## Update 1

For example, this is the data in my table.

**Store A:**
Apple iPhone,
Apple iPhone,
Android phone

**Store B:**
Apple iPhone,
Android Phone,
Android Phone

There are 3 records for each store.
And I would like my output to be:

1. Store name
2. Name of product
3. Total # of most popular items sold in each store

For example:

Store A, Apple iPhone, 2
Store B, Android Phone, 2

## Original post

I have 2 columns in my table: 
1) Store ID and 
2) Item name

I would like to write a query that returns:
1) Store ID
2) Item name
3) Total no. of **most popular items** in each store

I have seen few methods:
1) Over partition
2) Inner Join

but not sure which is the best method to move ahead with.

Any help appreciated.

### Sample data:

StoreID Product
1   Apple iPhone
1   Android phone
1   Android phone
1   Apple iPhone
1   Apple charger
2   Android phone
2   Apple iPhone
2   Apple charger
2   Android phone
3   Apple iPhone
3   Apple charger
3   Android phone
3   Apple iPhone

### Desired output:

Store ID    Product
1   Apple iPhone
2   Android phone
3   Apple IPhone

Comment: So pick one and see how it works out for you. Or try them both and see which one works best for your needs. Making no effort at all to do either won't get you far.

Comment: You should provide some sample data and explain what makes an item "popular"

Comment: @GermanC A popular item is one that has the highest sales volume i.e. the one that appears the most often in the table. Let me provide some sample data.

Comment: So you need ONE result per store, with the most popular item?

Comment: Please provide outline schema, sample data, and the SQL you've tried, the results you got, the results you wanted, and (usually) you should identify which DBMS you are using as there can be differences in the answers.  It really isn't clear from the description how you know how many of each item are sold at each store.  If you have just two columns and repeated rows, you're violating normal forms (repeating data).

Comment: @GermanC yeap, that's right!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your response. Apologies, I'm pretty new to Sql and havent used Stackoverflow for a while. I have since updated the post with more info. Ron got what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set-up:

```
create table sales
(
    id       integer,
    store    varchar(8),
    product  varchar(16)
);

insert into sales (id, store, product) values (1, 'Store A', 'Apple iPhone');
insert into sales (id, store, product) values (2, 'Store A', 'Apple iPhone');
insert into sales (id, store, product) values (3, 'Store A', 'Android Phone');
insert into sales (id, store, product) values (4, 'Store B', 'Apple iPhone');
insert into sales (id, store, product) values (5, 'Store B', 'Android Phone');
insert into sales (id, store, product) values (6, 'Store B', 'Android Phone');
```

The Query:

```
select
    z.store,
    z.product,
    z.volume
from
    (
        select
            store,
            max(volume) as top_volume
        from
            (
                select 
                    store,
                    product,
                    count(*) as volume
                from
                    sales
                group by
                    store,
                    product
            ) x
        group by
            store
    ) y
    join
        (
            select 
                store,
                product,
                count(*) as volume
            from
                sales
            group by
                store,
                product
        ) z
    on  
        y.store = z.store and
        y.top_volume = z.volume;
```

Result:

```
  store  |    product    | volume 
---------+---------------+--------
 Store A | Apple iPhone  |      2
 Store B | Android Phone |      2
(2 rows)
```

If there's a tie for the top spot this query will return both products.

I used PostgreSQL but this will work in any of the leading databases.  Feel free to ask if you don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try this method. The method that I figured works too.

Comment: Thanks again for providing the context!

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry about the delay in my response.

This approach will work for the case where you have 2 items sharing popularity within a store:

```
select store, product, count(*) as total
from sales s
group by store, product
having count(*) = (
                    select top 1 count(*)
                    from sales
                    where store = s.store
                    group by store, product
                    order by count(*) desc
                  )
```

Since you are learning SQL, it is important for you to notice that you are able to reference the outer table ("s" in this case) within the inner query which gets the maximum number of the same item for each store.

Spend some time reading it and let me know if you need further clarification.

PS: Credits to @Ron Ballard on the test schema!

Comment: Did it work for you? Is it solved? You should select an answer :) @dave